# ELRTE ( WYSIWYG HTML-editor ) for IE 11

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, elrte

We use JQUERY 1.6.4 , ELRTE WYSIWYG HTML-editor in our software. Now we are going to provide support for IE 11 for our software.

Based on the URL : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/bg182625(v=vs.85).aspx , IE 11 came with some **removed api features** . Now **for adding IE 11 support** for the software, we need to **upgrade the JQUERY** to the latest version ( probably JQUERY 1.11 ) which has been released after the release of IE 11 so that JQUERY works with IE 11. But it looks like **latest version of ELRTE WYSIWYG HTML-editor(https://github.com/Studio-42/elRTE) needs older version of JQUERY ( jquery-1.6.1.min.js, jquery-ui-1.8.13.custom.min.js ).**

Please correct me if i have proveded any incorrect data above.

Now my question is : **IE 11 needs JQUERY 1.11 and ELRTE editor needs JQUERY 1.6 . Now , How to make the ELRTE WYSIWYG HTML-editor work with IE 11 ?**

Helpful answers are really appreciated ...

Answer (score 0):

I commented the post about this matter.

[elrte doesn't work with Internet Explorer 11 (IE11)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20347154/elrte-doesnt-work-with-internet-explorer-11-ie11)

Would it be able to be useful to you?

- elRTE 1.3
- elFinder 2.1_n
- jquery-1.11.2
- jquery-ui-1.10.1

Comment: there is no links :(